# ActivemQ Artemis with MQTT protocol

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-artemis

```
[AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:559] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedActiveMQ' defined in class path resource [com/els/galaxy/gateway/ArtemisConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManagerFactory.stripPasswordParameters(Ljava/util/Map;)V
[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:597] - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'readPersistenceUnit'
=[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:597] - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'writePersistentUnit'
[session:167] - node0 Stopped scavenging
[ContextHandler:1045] - Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@7bebe5de{application,/galaxy-gateway,[file:///C:/Users/basireddym/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.7636853341168462882.86/],UNAVAILABLE}
[AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer:102] -
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to ask a question here.

Comment: You just pasted was seem to be an extract from logs. What's your actual question, what did you try? Please post a [mcve].